# how to make responsive the text in a box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm sorry I'll send a lot of code but it's my second design so I'm really a newbie. So I couldn't divide the code. Because maybe the mistake can be somewhere I couldn't see right now.

The problem is the texts in my first box doesn't narrow when I narrow the page.

I can't see the problem. The other two boxes are ok but what is different in the first box? This box is problematic :) I had to add another margin rule for that box too.

[The JSfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/Dr277/ca6qLngu/12/)

this is my HTML,

```
    <body>
   <div class="container">
     <header class="header">
       <h1 id="title" class="head-text">Funny Survey</h1>
       <p id="description" class="description head-text">Do not take this form seriously, but it is highly recommended that you answer the questions anyway.&#128540</p>
     </header>
     <form id="survey-form">
       <div class="boxes">
         <div class="box1">
           <div class="name">
             <label id="name-label" for="name">Name</label>
             <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
           </div>
           <div class="email">
             <label id="email-label" for="email">Email</label>
             <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required />
           </div>
           <div class="state-of-mind">
             <p>If age is only a state of mind, which category best describes your state of mind right now?</p>
             <select id="dropdown" name="age-drop" class="state-of-mind" required>
               <option disabled selected value>Select your state of mind</option>
               <option value="child">Cheeky Child </option>
               <option value="teenager">Tormented Teenager</option>
               <option value="mid-age">Mad Mid-Lifer‍♀️</option>
               <option value="old">Groovy Grandparent</option>
               <option value="other">Other</option>
             </select>
           </div>
         </div>

         <div class="box2">
           <div class="number">
             <label id="number-label" for="number">I am an odd number. Take away one letter and I become even. What number am I?</label>
             <input type="number" name="odd" id="number" min="6" max="8" class="number" placeholder="?" />
           </div>
           <div class="dog-cat">
             <p>Are you a dog person, or a cat person?</p>
             <label>
               <input name="dog-cat" value="dog" type="radio" checked />Dog
             </label>
             <label>
               <input name="dog-cat" value="cat" type="radio" />Cat 
             </label>
             <label>
               <input name="dog-cat" value="not-sure" type="radio" />Not sure 
             </label>
             <div class="superpower">
               <p>Which superpower would you like to have?
                 <span class="clue">(Check all that apply)</span></p>
               <label>
                 <input name="superpower" type="checkbox" value="mind-read">Mind Reading
               </label>
               <label>
                 <input name="superpower" type="checkbox" value="invisibility">Invisibility
               </label>
               <label>
                 <input name="superpower" type="checkbox" value="teleportation">Teleportation
               </label>
               <label>
                 <input name="superpower" type="checkbox" value="Flying">Flying
               </label>
               <label>
                 <input name="superpower" type="checkbox" value="have-superpower">I have already a superpower
               </label>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="box3">
           <div class="tech">
             <p>What’s the best tech invention of the 21st Century?</p>
             <textarea id="invention" class="tech" name="inventions" placeholder="Enter your comment here..." rows="15" style="width: 100%; 
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888888 inset; 
            background-color: var(--background);"></textarea>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="submit-container">
         <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">
           Submit 
         </button>
       </div>


     </form>


   </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

And this is the CSS

```
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap');

  :root {
    --background: #E4E4E4;
    --box-color: #1e121e;
    --color-text: #FEFEFE;
    --color-text-hover: #ad3e46;
    --header-text: #D9414B;
    --main-font: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    --border-color: #a5a5a5;
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background-color: var(--background);
    font-family: var(--main-font);
  }

  .container {
    margin-top: 2em;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #b8353d;
  }

  .header {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-flow: column;
    padding: 15px;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-image: url('https://sourceofmine.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/9/8/119868229/form_orig.png') 125 / 19px round;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #title {
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  .boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 8em;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-right: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .box1,
  .box2,
  .box3 {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    max-width: 30%;
    background-color: var(--box-color);
    color: var(--color-text);
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 9px;
    box-shadow: 10px 8px 6px #5e4464;
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .boxes {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
    }

    .box1,
    .box2,
    .box3 {
      font-size: 0.9em;
    }
  }

  .boxes :hover {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    color: #D9414B;
  }

  .email,
  .name,
  .state-of-mind {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
  }

  .name::placeholder,
  .email::placeholder,
  .number::placeholder,
  .tech::placeholder {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }

  .dog-cat,
  .superpower,
  .number {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
  }

  .submit-container {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
  }

  .submit-button {
    width: 250px;
    align-self: center;
    color: #FEFEFE;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: var(--main-font);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .submit-button::before {
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    background-size: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    width: calc(100% + 6px);
    height: calc(100% + 6px);
    animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;

  }

  .submit-button:active {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bolder;

  }

  .submit-button:active:after {
    background: transparent;
  }

  .submit-button:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .submit-button:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--box-color);
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  @keyframes glowing {
    0% {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }

    50% {
      background-position: 400% 0;
    }

    100% {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that the content inside of the container has no CSS saying how wide it's supposed to be.

To fix the issue, you need to tell all the elements inside the container to have a width of 100% meaning 'fill the parent element'. It looks like you already have a spot in CSS were you can do this.

On line 93 of your css you have:

```
.email,
.name,
.state-of-mind {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-family: var(--main-font);
  width: 100%;    /* add this line  */
}
```

Add that last line in there and that should help you out a bit.

On a side note, try not to use so many classes and divs, doing so makes your code a little cleaner and helps to find problems easier when stuff like this happens :D

Comment: After two hours, this finally solved my problem. Yes, you're right I've used too much divs. I'll definitely write my future codes more efficient :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding media queries and altering the padding or size of the text as the box gets smaller. That should work.
Check out these examples:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: yes I've tried them. But it didn't work. I think the problem is the text width is limited by the dropdown menu width.
But I couldn't find a way to narrow it down.